# Using matplotlib colormap with sparse matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a sparse matrix with `matplotlib.pylab` and `scipy.sparse`, but I want each row to take on a different color (not necessarily in regular intervals) from a gradient colormap (right now, I am thinking of using the 'jet' colormap). I want to choose which values in the gradient are used for which rows with a list of integers that index into the gradient colormap. I assume I will need to use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` somehow, but I'm not sure.

Here is some of the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import scipy.sparse as sps

m = sps.rand(16,16, density=0.25)
row = m.row
col = m.col
# gradient indexes into the colormap
gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 16)
# Plot the sparse matrix.
# TODO: Use a colormap in pylab.spy() or elsewhere?
plt.spy(m, markersize=5)
plt.show()
```